# pygame window won't close when clicking quitbuttons or the red X at top

Tags: python, pygame

I use a system like this which should theoretically work to close the window:

```
while running:
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

import random
import sys

# Set width and height of window
(width, height) = (400, 600)

# Sets the colours
background_colour = (0, 2, 20)
white = (255, 255, 255)

# creates window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Dodger")

screen.fill(background_colour)


def gameLoop():
    # sets sprite starting coordinates
    rocketX = 200
    rocketY = 450

    leftX = 0
    leftY = -25
    leftWidth = random.randint(0, 300)

    # sets obstacle start speed
    obstacleSpeed = 1

    # sets starting score
    score = 0
    pygame.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font("Pixeled.ttf", 32)
    fontSmall = pygame.font.Font("Pixeled.ttf", 25)

    scoreX = 10
    scoreY = 10

    # All images/sprites
    # rocket
    rocket = pygame.image.load("rocket.png")
    rocket = pygame.transform.smoothscale(rocket, (50, 100))

    # background image
    backgroundSpace = pygame.image.load("spacesky.png")
    backgroundSpace = pygame.transform.rotate(backgroundSpace, 90)
    backgroundColour = (10, 32, 61)

    running = True
    while running:
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # sets rectangles for obstacles
        leftObstacle = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, pygame.Rect(leftX, leftY, leftWidth, 25))
        rightObstacle = pygame.draw.rect(
            screen, white, pygame.Rect(leftWidth + 100, leftY, width, 25)
        )
        rocketRec = pygame.draw.rect(
            screen, backgroundColour, pygame.Rect(rocketX + 10, rocketY, 30, 75)
        )

        # sets score text
        displayScore = font.render(str(score), True, (105, 105, 105))

        # makes cursor invisible
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

        # draws new layer over screen
        screen.blit(backgroundSpace, (0, 0))

        # tracks the mosue location
        mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # draws rectangle behind rocket
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, backgroundColour, rocketRec)

        # displays the rocket
        screen.blit(rocket, (rocketX, rocketY))

        # sets rocket horizontal position
        if mouseX > width - 50:
            rocketX = width - 50
        else:
            rocketX = mouseX

        # displays the score
        screen.blit(displayScore, (scoreX, scoreY))

        # creates the moving obstacles
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, leftObstacle)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, rightObstacle)

        leftY = leftY + obstacleSpeed

        # brings obstacle back to top
        if leftY > 600:
            leftY = -25
            leftWidth = random.randint(0, 300)
            score = score + 1
            if obstacleSpeed >= 6:
                obstacleSpeed = 6
            else:
                obstacleSpeed = obstacleSpeed + 0.2

        if rocketRec.colliderect(leftObstacle) or rocketRec.colliderect(rightObstacle):
            collisionScreen()


def startScreen():
    lightGrey = (200, 200, 200)
    darkGrey = (165, 165, 165)
    lightGrey2 = (200, 200, 200)
    darkGrey2 = (165, 165, 165)

    # background image
    backgroundSpace = pygame.image.load("spacesky.png")
    backgroundSpace = pygame.transform.rotate(backgroundSpace, 90)
    backgroundColour = (10, 32, 61)

    pygame.init()
    fontSmall = pygame.font.Font("Pixeled.ttf", 25)

    running = True
    while running:
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # start screen

        # makes cursor visible
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

        # tracks the mosue location
        mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # draws new layer over screen
        screen.blit(backgroundSpace, (0, 0))

        # Puts on logo
        logo = pygame.image.load("name.png")
        logo = pygame.transform.smoothscale(logo, (500, 300))
        screen.blit(logo, (-40, 10))

        # creates start button
        startRecU = pygame.draw.rect(screen, darkGrey, pygame.Rect(120, 270, 160, 60))
        startRec = pygame.draw.rect(screen, lightGrey, pygame.Rect(125, 275, 150, 50))
        startText = fontSmall.render("START", True, (0, 0, 0))
        # displays the start text
        screen.blit(startText, (135, 262))

        # detects if mouse is hovering over button
        if 280 > mouseX > 120 and 330 > mouseY > 270:
            darkGrey = (200, 200, 200)
            lightGrey = (165, 165, 165)
        else:
            lightGrey = (200, 200, 200)
            darkGrey = (165, 165, 165)

        # detects if start button is clicked
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 280 > mouseX > 120 and 330 > mouseY > 270:
                gameLoop()

        # creates quit button
        quitRecU = pygame.draw.rect(screen, darkGrey2, pygame.Rect(120, 350, 160, 60))
        quitRec = pygame.draw.rect(screen, lightGrey2, pygame.Rect(125, 355, 150, 50))
        quitText = fontSmall.render("QUIT", True, (0, 0, 0))
        # displays the start text
        screen.blit(quitText, (156, 340))

        # detects if mouse is hovering over button
        if 280 > mouseX > 120 and 410 > mouseY > 350:
            darkGrey2 = (200, 200, 200)
            lightGrey2 = (165, 165, 165)
        else:
            lightGrey2 = (200, 200, 200)
            darkGrey2 = (165, 165, 165)

        # detects if quit button is clicked
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 280 > mouseX > 120 and 410 > mouseY > 350:
                running = False


def collisionScreen():
    lightGrey = (200, 200, 200)

    darkGrey = (165, 165, 165)
    lightGrey2 = (200, 200, 200)
    darkGrey2 = (165, 165, 165)

    # background image
    backgroundSpace = pygame.image.load("spacesky.png")
    backgroundSpace = pygame.transform.rotate(backgroundSpace, 90)
    backgroundColour = (10, 32, 61)

    # explosion
    explosion = pygame.image.load("explosion.png")
    explosion = pygame.transform.smoothscale(explosion, (100, 100))

    pygame.init()
    fontSmall = pygame.font.Font("Pixeled.ttf", 25)
    fontMini = pygame.font.Font("Pixeled.ttf", 15)

    running = True
    while running:
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # draws new layer over screen
        screen.blit(backgroundSpace, (0, 0))

        # makes cursor visible
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

        # tracks the mosue location
        mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # displays the explosion
        screen.blit(explosion, (150, 400))

        # creates play again button
        playAgainRecU = pygame.draw.rect(screen, darkGrey, pygame.Rect(120, 270, 160, 60))
        playAgainRec = pygame.draw.rect(screen, lightGrey, pygame.Rect(125, 275, 150, 50))
        playAgainText = fontMini.render("PLAY AGAIN", True, (0, 0, 0))
        # displays the start text
        screen.blit(playAgainText, (135, 278))

        # detects if mouse is hovering over button
        if 280 > mouseX > 120 and 330 > mouseY > 270:
            darkGrey = (200, 200, 200)
            lightGrey = (165, 165, 165)
        else:
            lightGrey = (200, 200, 200)
            darkGrey = (165, 165, 165)

        # detects if play button is clicked
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 280 > mouseX > 120 and 330 > mouseY > 270:
                gameLoop()

        # creates quit button
        quit2RecU = pygame.draw.rect(screen, darkGrey2, pygame.Rect(120, 350, 160, 60))
        quit2Rec = pygame.draw.rect(screen, lightGrey2, pygame.Rect(125, 355, 150, 50))
        quit2Text = fontSmall.render("QUIT", True, (0, 0, 0))
        # displays the start text
        screen.blit(quit2Text, (156, 340))

        # detects if mouse is hovering over button
        if 280 > mouseX > 120 and 410 > mouseY > 350:
            darkGrey2 = (200, 200, 200)
            lightGrey2 = (165, 165, 165)
        else:
            lightGrey2 = (200, 200, 200)
            darkGrey2 = (165, 165, 165)

        # detects if quit button is clicked
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 280 > mouseX > 120 and 410 > mouseY > 350:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        running = False


startScreen()
```

Comment: Your code has errors, I cannot run it

Comment: You should edit your code to only include the function in which you're having this trouble. As it is, there are 3 functions and 8 `for event in pygame.event.get()` loops.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. You can't just post hundreds of lines of code, much of which is either unnecessary for the problem, or things we cannot run because it's using images we don't have.

Comment: Also, you can't have multiple `pygame.event.get()` per frame, as each call empties the event queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty messy, try to do all your code to only one main loop (you have three now). This is how I suggest how it should be done.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Conststants, variables and images

startMenu = True
mainGame = False
collisionScreen = False



#Main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #All things that are supposed to happen can be pressed by the mouse (if statement)

    if startMenu:
        #Start Menu code


    elif mainGame:
        #Main game code

    elif collisionScreen:
        #Collision screen code



    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60) #fps
```

I hope it helps you, Adam